# Explanation of the awk command used in the context below

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

Prvt_Yadv wrote some code to explain how to install packages from a list of packages in a text file using a script.

My question is could anybody break it down as to why he chose the combination he chose.

I was able to get it work not using the above method, but it was temperamental.

My Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#=====================================
# Path to Instalation & Scripts
#=====================================
path2Dev="/home/`id -u -n`/Development/Install"
input="$path2Dev/DepList_Fedora.txt"
#--------------------------------------

#=====================================
## Make stringBuild Global
#=====================================
export stringBuild=" "
#--------------------------------------

#=====================================
## Build string with no Fluff 
##  from List of packages
#--------------------------------------

while IFS= read -r line
do
    stringBuild+=" $line"

done < "$input"

###   End of Loop  ### 

#############################
# Get Dependencys for Build 
#  from values in ("input")
#============================
sudo dnf group install --assumeyes "C Development Tools and Libraries" ;
echo $stringBuild ## De-Bug 
sudo dnf install --assumeyes "$stringBuild" 
## Tried `$stringBuild` and $stringbuild
```

Prvt_Yadv Code:

```
sudo dnf install --assumeyes $(awk -F ',' 'BEGIN {ORS=" "} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print $i}}' $input)
```

Why does that seem to work more reliably then my original code? Could you explain why?

`DepList_Fedora.txt`

```
bison-devel 
 arm-none-eabi-gcc
 arm-none-eabi-gcc-cs 
 arm-none-eabi-gcc-cs-c++ 
 arm-none-eabi-binutils-cs 

 patch
 gperftools-devel
 ncurses-devel
 cdk
 cdk-devel
 ccrtp
 ccrtp-devel
 doxygen 
 python3-hidapi
 mingw64-hidapi
 hidapi-devel
 xclip
 autoconf213
 libtool-ltdl-devel
 python2-devel
 guile
 nodejs-node-expat
 mingw64-libltdl
 libusb-devel
 libusb
 autoconf
 texinfo
 libtool
 libftdi-devel
 gcc-arm-linux-gnu
 flex
 gperf
 git
 bison
 zlib
```

Comment: I think you have to explain _in what way_ the "temperamental" code is behaving temperamentally.

Comment: The first code converts a list of names, one on each line, into a single line of space-separated names. The second code does the same but *also* converts comma-separated names that are on the same line into space-separated names. Can you share more about what the input file `DepList_Fedora.txt` looks like?

Comment: Kusalananda - Temperamental, adding my comments broke it :(

Comment: drewbenn - I added the list. Ahh so after the -f, the ',' is the deliminator. What does 'BEGIN {ORS=" "} do?

Comment: ORS is the _Output Record Separator_ - so `awk`'s output will be delimited by spaces. I'd've used nulls `\0` and sent it to `xargs -0 --no-run-on-empty dnf ...`.

Comment: -Rich Awesome, that make sense, but the special parameter your used "--no-run-on-empty"  Is that a check to ensure that the list is not empty?